# what is the simplest way to connect to a website and read data from it

Tags: android, http

i would like to connect to a website and process or read data from it.

1-Is it possible to so by android activity and what is the simplest way to do so?

2-can the emulator simulates internet connection or not.

Updated:
please provide me with examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here is tutorial for connecting the service and fetch the data in android

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android

2.If your system having the internet connection and need to give proper permissions in   your   manifest file, then you can working with your simulator to connect the service and fetching your data.

permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Answer (score 0):

1. The simplest way to read data from a site is that particular site to offer you an API through you can the consume content, if it does not offer an API, then you would make a request and parse the HTML response looking for what you need.
2. Yes, emulator can simulate internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

creates the Permission in Android Manifest.xml file like the link give below

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

then in activity 
you can use url to open the internet in your activity

hence the emulator can load data from internet